# MySQL: Dropdown list showing different value than the one sent

Tags: mysql, forms, select, dropdown, libreoffice-base

Is it possible to have a dropdown list in a MySQL form to show a list of values from one field, yet sent a value from another?

I want to choose from the list of values in a "Name" field, but for the value actually sent by the form to be the related "ID" value.

Comment: Not only possible, but probably the most common scenario. However, MySQL does not display forms, and the [tag:forms] tag is very vague, indicating no specific technology, so you cannot be answered any more specifically than that as to how to actually achieve it. There is no "MySQL form" as MySQL is the database layer, and forms are the presentation layer; are you talking about a .NET form, a HTML form, a Cocoa form, ...?

Comment: I'm using LibreOffice Base. Mostly I'm asking about a possible SQL command that would show "Name", but result in sending "ID".

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out. The answer is to create a "list" type field, then create a query including first the displayed value and then the value sent - so:

```
SELECT "Name", "ID"
```

The visible one will alwyas be the first field, but in the field's properties the "Linked field" can be changed to choose which of the selected fields is sent. In this case it would be 1 (the first one, "Name", is 0).